# Regex to include comma in java split function

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter, backslash

I want to have a split function that splits String based on delimiter "," but that should not be taken as delimiter in some cases.

lets say:

```
String= "one,two,three"
Array=String.split(",");
Arrayoutput=["one","two","three"];
```

then if

```
String="one,two\\,three";
Array=String.split("???");
```

so the output =["one","two,three"];

So how to write a regular expression in place of "???" so that it includes "," but does not include "\\,". Something like  "([,]&[^\\,])" .

Also the when to read comma as String instead of delimiter is configurable, I took \ for now but can be anything.

P.S: I can solve it with the following pseudo code:

```java
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
if(s.charAt(i)=="\\,"){}
else if(s.charAt(i)==','){then split it;}
}
```

but I am looking for the most efficient and fastest solution, any other Ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: For input - `"one,two\\,three"`, if we split by `,` shouldn't the output be `["one", "two\\,three"]`?

Comment: By having "regex" as a tag it seems you want to split on characters matching a regex, but that cannot be the case as you want `"one,two"` to become `"onetwo"`; i.e., you want to remove the first comma but not split on it.

Comment: Perhaps split on `(?<!\\),[,\s]*+(?=[^,\s]|$)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sciKaM/1) or get all the matches instead `[^,\\]+(?:\\.[^,\\]*)*` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XN9QSZ/1) Note to double escape the backslash in Java

Comment: 1.Sorry for the confusion I want to split on , and not \\, and I have edited it accordingly and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Negative Look Behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). You can check this out in [regexp10.com](https://regex101.com/r/6P0Ap0/1).

```java
public static String[] split(String str) {
    final String regexp = "(?<!\\\\),";
    return str.split(regexp);
}
```

Then the client's code will look like this:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split("one,two,three")));    // ["one","two","three"] 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split("one,two\\,three")));  // ["one","two\,three"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You likely want a [negative look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which will look for a comma *not* preceded by a backslash. Many backslashes are necessary as we need to not only escape the backslashes in a string, but also in the resulting regex.

```java
"(?<!\\\\),"
```

With Java 12 and later, raw string literals are supported, and can save us from some of this escaping.

```java
`(?<!\\\\),`
```

Now, if we want to split only on commas preceded by a backslash, we'd use a *positive* look behind.

```java
`(?<=\\),`
```

A demonstration in Python because its interactive interpreter presents the information in an easy to understand manner. Python has its own raw string syntax and the *regular expressions* themselves are the same.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"(?<!\\),", r"1,2\,3")
['1', '2\\,3']
>>> re.split(r"(?<=\\),", r"1,2\,3")
['1,2\\', '3']
```